# Setting up a website to internet traffic, Unable to forward a port or use local ssh for raspberryPi

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, hosting, portforwarding

I am setting up a website and am trying to expose the content so that some people im working with can view it on their devices.

**The Setup(hardware)**

- Mac and windows computers for development (would like to ssh into raspberry pi as well)
- Netgear Router (all devices locally connected to this router)
- RaspberryPi 400 (hosting the website)

**The Setup(Software)**

- Angular web app
- express server
- nginx server hosting
- database stuff

**What Works**

- raspberryPi is connected and hosting the website locally
- Can navigate to the webpage by the pi's ip address on local

**Things That Have Defeated Me**

- ssh into pi from mac or pc (have enabled ssh on pi, can ping pi, cannot ssh pi@ connection timeout)
- port forwarding (have logged into router, forwarded port -> portchecktool.com => timeout)
- static ip on pi (have entered wlan0 interface to /etc/dchpcd.conf reboot, still auto assigned ip "file didnt exist before weird")
- need root access to change stuff in var/www folder super annoying to sudo cp websitedir -r var/www/html

BLUL:
If anyone has gone through this before it would be a massive help, I am a software engineer and love the algorithms, finding im not loving the network engineering.

I also realize this is an annoying question because the first few rounds are probably going to be clarifying questions that ill have to answer and should have known to share during the first post... Forgive my ignorance and bless you in advance!

Now that I have stepped away and come back I think I set something up wrong here. when i run hostname -I or the ifconfig commands on the pi i get 10.0.0.16 over my lan, so this is what i have been trying to ssh into, but if i navigate to this ip i get the webpage im hosting from there. I think i have made a mistake hosting the website on that ip so i cant ssh through it. Not sure but maybe this will help anyone looking at this?

Verbose ssh log

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/camer/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.12 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.12 [10.0.0.12] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:0000025632DE5650
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.12 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.12 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I know i shouldnt be using dynamic ip, im working on that too

UPDATE:

Ok raspberryPi has reserved local ip so its static, got myself a noip domain, opened a port on the pi and have the site being hosted through it, and ssh now works.

The only thing i cant get to work is the port forward, ive forwarded the port on my router, but the router is connected to a modem. Im thinking that maybe the isp is blocking it? idk

Answer (score 0):

I was double NAT'd, just put my modem/router into bridge mode and all was well.